# How to make Ag-Grid sort % Columns

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have columns in a react Ag-Grid that sort percentage columns like 5.08% as a string. how can I get ag-grid to sort them as number values instead? the data coming from the server is already formatted for 0.00 and there is a cell renderer that appends the % sign. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the column definition you can provide a [comparator function](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0). This function is provided various parameters:

```
percentColumn.comparator = function (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {
    return parseFloat(valueA) - parseFloat(valueB);
}
```

I am not quite sure how having the cell renderer would affect what `valueA` and `valueB` are, but doing something like the above should work.